# how to take distinct values of a field in one mongo collection and map it to another field in a different collection. For axample

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Collection 1:

Name : Radan
Job : xxx

Name : Dammy
Job : yyy

Name: Radan
Job:xxx

Collection 2:

Name : Radan
Expiry: 2021-08-09

Name: Dammy
Expiry: 2021-08-07

Name : Radan
Expiry: 2021-08-09

The output should look like:

Name : Raddy Expiry : 2021-08-09
Name: Dammy Expiry : 2021-08-07

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you are asking you dont even need the collection1.

You can do it like bellow, aggregate in Collection2

```js
aggregate(
[ {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : "$Name",
    "Expiry" : {
      "$first" : "$Expiry"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$addFields" : {
    "Name" : "$_id"
  }
}, {
  "$project" : {
    "_id" : 0
  }
} ]
)
```

But i think you are asking how to join like SQL, for that you can use `$lookup` and merge with ROOT

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jmMYOUZJNG3)

```js
db.c1.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Name",
      "doc": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Name": "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "c2",
      "let": {
        "name_p": "$Name"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$$name_p",
                "$Name"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "joined"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$joined",
              0
            ]
          },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "joined",
      "_id"
    ]
  }
])
```

Next time if you can give the data in valid JSON, and the output in valid JSON, and take some more time with the question, i think you want other things and you ask for other things.Also its better to search for similar questions, so we dont repeat them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am sorry. I wanted to say there are documents in collection 1 for which there is no entry in collection 2, also there are documents in collection 1 which has an entry in collection 2 but no expiry date so i am trying to catch all of them. When there is no expiry date or no entry in collection 2 the docs remains in coll1 forever and consumes more space